# How to get views list from salesForce service?

Tags: webservices

im using https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/28.0 URL, 
I get the list of tables from salesforce
Tables:- AcceptedEventRelation,Account,etc,..

But I dont know to get views from salesforce service, I tried below code to get table list.
 using (sforce.SforceService svc = _connInfo.CreateInstance())
            {DescribeGlobalResult dgr = svc.describeGlobal();}

I need to find:-
Views
 - FieldRelationships
 - PickListValues
 - TableRelationships

Answer (score 0):

Rest Api do support list views describe as follow:

1. /vXX.X/sobjects/{sobjectType}/listviews

Below is the example of the curl request :

```
curl https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/Account/listviews -H "Authorization: Bearer token"
```

1. You can implement this curl request into the desired programming
   language.
2. You Should just replace the accesstoken with the sessionId you received from connection.

What is your programming language ?

Let me know if you need more help.

Thanks

Comment: Programming Language is C#  .

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested ?